# Question about Tails installation

Tags: tails

I am interested in installation of Tails to Hard Disk. I tryed to make USB flash disk with Tails then use information from it. Cant find anser in manual. Help me plz.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking... you can't.  Digging a bit deeper, you'll find that it can be done manually with some work, but even then persistent storage won't work unless your Hard Disk is attached via USB.

If you happen to be using a USB hard-drive, it should be easier.  You just have to remember to remove `live-media=removable` at the [***Tails Bootloader Menu***](https://web.archive.org/web/20190102040950im_/https://tails.boum.org/install/inc/screenshots/tails_boot_menu.png) (just hit tab)